# Перенос приложений в Django

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование

Есть у меня на сайте несколько приложений, и сайт выглядит примерно так:

```
site/
../manage.py
../static/
../templates/
../site/
..../apps.py
..../settings.py
../app1/
..../apps.py
../app2/
..../apps.py
```

Во время разработки я решил перенести приложения в отдельный каталог, чтобы сайт стал примерно таким:

```
site/
../manage.py
../static/
../templates/
../site/
..../apps.py
..../settings.py
../django_apps/
..../app1/
....../apps.py
..../app2/
....../apps.py
```

Мне пришлось переименовать все все приложения из `app1` в `django_apps.app1` в `settings.py` и локальных `app.py`, но у меня есть уже много миграций и заполненная база данных, и миграции не дают мне выполнить это. Возможен ли такой перенос, чтобы не пришлось перезаполнять данные, и как это нужно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Окей, было несложно, но я справился.

Для начала мне пришлось, собственно, переместить катологи приложений в один общий каталог `django_apps`.

Затем в `settings.py` переименовать все `INSTALLED_APPS` из `'app_name'` в `'django_apps.app_name'`, чтобы при запуске они могли импортироваться, а также в классе конфигурации приложений в `apps.py` копировать атрибут `name = 'app_name'` в `label = 'app_name'`, а сам `name` изменить в `name = 'django_apps.app_name'`. Сделано это потому, что `name` хранит путь к приложению, а само имя приложения и талицы хранится в `'label'`.
Собственно, вот и всё, но да не всё. В конце необходимо изменить все импорты из других приложений и миграций из `from app_name.tools import something` в `from django_apps.app_name.tools import something`, и не забыть переименвать все `app_name.models.functions` в `django_apps.app_name.models.functions` внутри миграций.
Вот и всё, оказалось, не так уж сложно.